# Getting grandparent directory of a file using Perl

Tags: perl

Any thoughts on getting grandparent directory of a file using Perl. Currently, I am able to get parent directory of file currently being executed in the following way

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd;

my ($parentDir, $grandParent);

$parentDir = Cwd::realpath();
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you actually want the parent directory, and not the grandparent, as `realpath` returns the current working directory.

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;

print "Parent Dir: ", abs_path(File::Spec->updir()), "\n";
```

However, to get the grandparent, the following would work:

```
print "Gramps: ", abs_path(File::Spec->catdir((File::Spec->updir) x 2)), "\n";
```

Comment: This is really nice. How does File::Spec->catdir((File::Spec->updir) x 2) work ? Isn't x 2 an operator for lists?

Comment: Yes, [`x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) is the repetition operator.  That was just a shortcut way of writing `(File::Spec->updir, File::Spec->updir)`.

Comment: I understand now, File::Spec->updir() returns ".." and not the actual parent directory

Comment: Correct, it returns the string representation of the parent directory in a platform independent way.  Btw, could've avoided the use of `Cwd` entirely by using `File::Spec->rel2abs(File::Spec->updir)`

Answer (score 1):

```
use Cwd;
use  File::Spec;

my ($parentDir, $grandParent);

$parentDir = Cwd::realpath();
print $parentDir,"\n";
my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir($parentDir);
pop @dirs;
my $grandParent = File::Spec->catdir( @dirs );
print $grandParent,"\n"
```